# How to deal with the function stabletre of stablelearner when the response is a multiple numerical one?

Tags: r

Here my code to fit a tree model:

```
paluTree.sub3.75 <- partykit::ctree(I(DensitePf^.25) + I(DensitePm^.25) ~ Age + sexe + Temperature + Moustiquaire + Objet_gites + PrvPalu + RetenuEau + IndVegetation,
                                    data = subset.df,
                                    minsplit = 75,
                                    minbucket = 75,
                                    maxdepth = 4)
```

I would like to analyze the stability of the model using the function `stabletree()` of the package `stablelearner`

```
diag.stabilite <- stablelearner::stabletree(paluTree.sub3.75,B = 100)
```

which does not produce an error, but when i run `summary(diag.stabilite)` i obtain the following error message

```
Error in round(sapply(nm, function(n) { : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
also the following barplot(diag.stabilite) results in an error
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
  need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```